# print html tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, printing, tags

Thanks for reading!

```
var data = "<html><head><title>Hello</title></head><body>Hello Body</body></html>";
```

I want to print `data` including the HTML tags without having the browser rendering the HTML tags and just displaying "Hello Body".

I tried:

`str = str.replace("<", "");`

but in vain.

Comment: What do you mean by "print" exactly? Print where?

Comment: I think he means write that string to the browser with the tags escaped so they are visible on the page instead of parsed into the DOM.

Comment: What "practically EVERYTHING" have you tried?

Comment: @fredrik: The OP never mentions PHP, he's looking for a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Hey hey guys! Give me some time to respond to your comments! You can't downvote just like that! It's a valid question! If you don't have the patient to read or understand it - just ignore and move on!

Comment: Tesserex got me right!
@David Dorward - I asked in JavaScript! Do you expect me to nest JS and PHP?!!

Comment: @Sagar Hatekar — a bad question is a bad question, people can remove downvotes if it is edited so it stops being a bad question.

Comment: @David Dorward - With due respect, that's your judgement! I am new to javascript and struggling to stay afloat. I am asking a genuine question. People wouldn't be posting helpful answers here if it were a bad question. There would've been a time when you were a newbie here so please learn to appreciate others! Not everyone knows as much as you! Thank you!

Comment: @Sagar Hatekar — You don't need to be an expert in JavaScript to be more specific then "practically EVERYTHING". You don't need to be an expert in JavaScript to explain what you want to do in more detail when rsplak and Pekka ask you. The question isn't bad due to a lack of knowledge about JavaScript, it just doesn't have a decent amount of information in it.

Comment: @Cory Larson: true, dont know why I thought of php :S, comment removed

Comment: @DavidDorward - I don't care, I got my answers. Thanks to all the other helpful folks for taking your time out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 data = data.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

When the browser encounters `&lt;` (which is known as a character entity), it will replace it with a literal '<', enabling you to display the HTML tags on the page without them getting rendered.

`/</g` is a regular expression that just says "match all '<' in the string", and `g` means do it globally. Without the `g` it will only replace the first '<' it encounters.

And one final note, it's much better to use a library, such as jQuery, to do this. This is the kind of stuff that is easy to get wrong and miss edge cases on. Let the hardened, well tested and secure library function do it for you.

Comment: Awesome! Really thanks a TON for that piece of code. That helped!

Comment: I recommend following Christian Sciberras's answer, his approach is better.

Comment: Okay, Matt. Thanks! Yours was the first I tried and it worked. Since I was just using this for debugging, I would use your answer but yes, for a full-fledged product - Christian's answer would be the best pick!

Comment: This quick and practical solution of yours has saved me days of work!

Answer (score 10):

The actual (and safer fix) is as follows:

```
function htmlspecialchars(text){
    return jQuery('<div/>').text(text).html();
}
```

In pure javascript, that would be:

```
function htmlspecialchars(text){
    var tnd=document.createTextNode(text);
    var div=document.createElement("DIV");
    div.appendChild(tnd);
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: The OP is not specifying jQuery, but this is very clever! +1

Comment: @Pekka Well, I was typing the pure-javascript implementation, it takes some time :).

Comment: Nice! This is vastly superior to replacing `<` and `>`.

Comment: yup, this is the better answer for sure

Comment: Thanks Christian for an elegant answer!

Comment: It may be more elegant and maybe more reliable, but it's a lot slower than regular expressions, not saying it's bad, just something to be aware of.

Comment: @Juan Mendes - Considering it is more direct than the other approaches, I would argue that is a browser issue. On one browser it might be faster than the other. But then again, some specific browser may as well make use of a lousy implementation of regular expressions, again something one just can't really tell.

Comment: @Christian: I'm not sure what you mean, what I mean is that this approach requires DOM manipulation which is much slower than string manipulation in any browser.

Comment: @JuanMendes - That isn't entirely true. The actual DOM isn't modified, think of it like DOM-on-the fly. Now if actually appended to body and deleted later on, that would be quite slow. But "appending" a text element (one DOM item) and reading it back as html (which is a stored property), makes this more efficient than one expects at a first glance.

Answer (score 3):

It's ugly but you could try this (borrowed from Prototype's implementation of `escapeHTML()`):

```
var data = "<html> <head> <title> Hello </title> </head> <body> Hello Body </body> </html>"
    .replace(/&/g,'&amp;')
    .replace(/</g,'&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g,'&gt;');

document.write(data);
```

Of course creating a little helper function would be better.