# jquery convert HTML code to plain text

Tags: jquery, html, chat

I am doing a chat application. In that when I posted a html code it gives HTML executed  out put

For Eg if I posted as:

> ```
> <i><h1>welcome</h1></i>
> ```

it gives out put as

> ## welcome

but I need my out put same like as input. The actual output should be

> ```
> <i><h1>welcome</h1></i>
> ```

Could any one help me plz.. Thanks advance,,,

Comment: and -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627484/print-html-tags-in-javascript

Comment: and -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery

Answer (score 2):

you should use `pre` tag :-

```
<pre><i><h1>welcome</h1></i></pre>
```

**[Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)**

Answer (score 0):

$("div").text("test"); this is what you looking for.

You can use .text() to escape html characters.